# Type unknown[] is not assignable to type React.ReactNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, vite

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { List, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText, ListItem} from '@mui/material';
import LightbulbOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LightbulbOutlined';
import NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/NotificationsNoneOutlined';
import DeleteOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';


const mainListItems = () => {
    const navList = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Notes', icon: <LightbulbOutlinedIcon />},
        { id: 2, name: 'Reminders', icon:  <NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon /> },
        { id: 3, name: 'Bin', icon: <DeleteOutlinedIcon /> },
    ]

    return (
            <List>
                {
                    navList.map( list => (
                        <ListItem key={list.id} disablePadding sx={{display: 'block'}}>
                            <ListItemButton sx={{minHeight: 48, justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center', px: 2.5}}>
                                <ListItemIcon sx={{minWidth: 0, mr: open ? 3 : 'auto', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                                    {list.icon}
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary={list.name} sx={{opacity: open ? 1 : 0}}/>
                            </ListItemButton>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))
                }
            </List>
    )
}
```

I tried reducing the amount of code by using map to assign icon information. But it shows this error and I can't understand why it happens. Should I assign types to the attributes in the list?

line where error occurs :

```
navList.map( list => (
```

Full error message :

> Type unknown[] is not assignable to type React.ReactNode ...   Type
> unknown[] is not assignable to type ReactElement<any, string |
> JSXElementConstructor> | string | number | Iterable |
> ReactPortal | boolean     Type unknown[] is not assignable to type
> boolean

Comment: does your file has the correct extension? (.jsx or .tsx). Also maybe it can be a cache issue, restart your dev server to make sure it's not coming from that. I don't see any issues concerning the error you are receiving.

Comment: is navList a state variable?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Solutions should be posted as answers below. Don't forget to accept it to resolve this post. Or delete the post.

Comment: Component name is not a factor in my case. I don't consider that a general solution.

Comment: I tested your code and it does not give any typescript warning or any kind of error and it renders

Comment: Please show your tsconfig and package.json in your post.

Comment: No one has mentioned TypeScript, nor is it tagged.

Comment: @AshwinSamGeorge please approve the answer so that people do not post more answers to this question. I just spent 15 minutes writing an answer without realizing that GoodMan already posted the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to define a type for your NavItems. Then set the navList to be of type NavItems Array. `const navList: NavItem[]`.
2. There is the issue of convention as earlier mentioned; React treats lowercase JSX as React Elements. e.g `<div>`,`<section>`, etc. These are the HTML tags look-alikes that come preloaded with react. So whenever React sees a lowercase JSX `<mainListItems>` in this case, It will attempt to read it as an intrinsic element and fail. THIS IS WHY IT IS IMPORTANT TO FOLLOW THE CONVENTION OF USING the `<MainListItems/>` naming style for your `<Components/>`
3. [Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-lovelace-6o4cef?file=/src/App.tsx)

```js
type NavItem = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  icon: JSX.Element;
};
const MainListItems = () => {
  const navList: NavItem[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "Notes", icon: <LightbulbOutlinedIcon /> },
    { id: 2, name: "Reminders", icon: <NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon /> },
    { id: 3, name: "Bin", icon: <DeleteOutlinedIcon /> }
  ];

  return (
    <List>
      {navList.map((list) => (
        <ListItem key={list.id} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
          <ListItemButton
            sx={{
              minHeight: 48,
              justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
              px: 2.5
            }}
          >
            <ListItemIcon
              sx={{
                minWidth: 0,
                mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
                justifyContent: "center"
              }}
            >
              {list.icon}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={list.name} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
          </ListItemButton>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};
```

Comment: TypeScript was not mentioned nor tagged. Does this answer still apply?

Comment: The error shared is a typescript error. Typescript might have been configured to parse `.jsx` file extensions, hence the type error. Do you want the question to be tagged appropriately.

Comment: That's a fair point, and one that I haven't seen come up yet. In that case it's a matter of IDE config and not code.

Answer (score 2):

This code runs fine given that there's no problems with any of the imports. The only thing wrong here is that `mainListItems`should be `MainListItems` as all React components should have names starting with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because TypeScript cannot infer the return type of the `map()` function, which is an array of `unknown` type. To resolve this, you can explicitly type the return type of `map()` by using the `ReactNode[]` type:

```
navList.map((list): React.ReactNode => (
  // ...
))
```

This tells TypeScript that the `map()` function will return an array of React nodes, which is what is expected by the List component.

Comment: TypeScript was not mentioned nor tagged.

Answer (score 1):

`React`, namely `JSX` cares about the casing of the component names. Every component must start with an upper-cased letter. That is because JSX will not recognize it as a `React` component otherwise, but rather as a `JSX` element (i.e. `h1`, `div`, `p` etc.).

I should also note the importing scheme. Do not import using `import * as React from 'react'` unless you are sure that that is what you want to do. For 99% of cases, you should import as such:

```
import React, {FC, Fragment, ... other imports ...} from "react"
```

The difference is that the former imports every exportable from the module, whereas the latter imports only the specified exportables.

Next, there is no mention of TypeScript but this error seems to be a TypeScript error to me, so go ahead and assign a type to `newList`.

I tested this on fiddle and it worked fine, go ahead and try it on your end please.

```
const MainListItems = () => {
    const navList:Array<{ id: number, name: string, icon: JSX.Element }> = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Notes', icon: <LightbulbOutlinedIcon />},
        { id: 2, name: 'Reminders', icon:  <NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon /> },
        { id: 3, name: 'Bin', icon: <DeleteOutlinedIcon /> },
    ]

    return (
            <List>
                {
                    navList.map( list => (
                        <ListItem key={list.id} disablePadding sx={{display: 'block'}}>
                            <ListItemButton sx={{minHeight: 48, justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center', px: 2.5}}>
                                <ListItemIcon sx={{minWidth: 0, mr: open ? 3 : 'auto', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                                    {list.icon}
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary={list.name} sx={{opacity: open ? 1 : 0}}/>
                            </ListItemButton>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))
                }
            </List>
    )
}
```

This is because `TypeScript` strict mode will not allow attempts to render things that `JSX` doesn't understand. It must be a `React` component, `JSX` element, string, character, number etc. You can use `ReactNode` type insted of `JSX.Element` as well, because `JSX.Element` is a subset of `ReactNode`.